# How to capture arbitrary UNIX signals in Go

Tags: go, unix, signals

I can capture signals in go with [signal package](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/) but how can I capture signals from 34 (SIGRTMIN) to 64 (SIGRTMAX) inclusively ([link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-signals-traps.htm))? Golang calls them "signal 34", "signal 64" etc. but that's beyond the point. When I run "pkill -34" I want my application to notice it.

I can capture them when I capture all signals:

```
sigChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(sigChan)
```

However I don't want to catch all signals, I want only those that I mentioned before.

I'm also aware that I can capture individual signals like:

```
signal.Notify(sigChan, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGPOOL, syscall.SIGCLD ...)
```

But that requires signal constants and I can't find constants that correspond to signals that I want to capture. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Short answer*:

you can just declare new signals as typed constants of type `syscall.Signal`:

```
const (
    SIGRTMIN = syscall.Signal(0x22)
)
```

---

*Long answer (how it works):*

The `signal.Notify` function signature is:

```
Notify(c chan<- os.Signal, sig ...os.Signal)
```

where `os.Signal` is an interface defined as such:

```
// A Signal represents an operating system signal.
// The usual underlying implementation is operating system-dependent:
// on Unix it is syscall.Signal.
type Signal interface {
    String() string
    Signal() // to distinguish from other Stringers
}
```

Normally you would use the `signal.Notify` function as in your example:

```
signal.Notify(sigChan, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGPOOL, syscall.SIGCLD ...)
```

So if we go check the implementation of those constants in the `syscall` package we see:

```
SIGKILL   = Signal(0x9)
```

where this `Signal` from the `syscall` package is a defined type:

```
// A Signal is a number describing a process signal.
// It implements the os.Signal interface.
type Signal int

func (s Signal) Signal() {}

func (s Signal) String() string {
    // ... a few lines of code
}
```

It's just an underlying `int` with a no-op `Signal()` method and the Stringer implementation.

So you can declare your own constants the same way for the signals you want to catch, by converting arbitrary `int` values:

```
const (
    SIGRTMIN = syscall.Signal(0x22)
)

signal.Notify(sigChan, SIGRTMIN, /* etc. */)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the input provided, I made a small snippet to easily capture all SIGRT signals:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "os/signal"
    "os"
)

func getSIGRTchannel() chan os.Signal {
    sigChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    sigArr := make([]os.Signal, 31)
    for i := range sigArr {
        sigArr[i] = syscall.Signal(i + 0x22)
    }
    signal.Notify(sigChan, sigArr...)
    return sigChan
}

func main() {
    c := getSIGRTchannel()
    // Block until a signal is received.
    for {
        s := <-c
        fmt.Println("Got signal:", s)
    }
}
```

To play with it, run this program in one terminal window and send some signals to it from another terminal window.